# Rigid body in human character

Tags: rigging, rigidbody

How do I  make a human character a rigid body
for example

1. A human touching a table
2. A man walking on a plane mesh

Comment: can you try search this question on youtube ? > https://youtu.be/0haYapQ7l_U

Comment: Welcome to BSE. Your [previous identical question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/237967/rigid-body-in-human-character) was closed for lacking detail and clarity.  People want to help.  To have it re-opened, please heed the requests there and edit additional details into your original question, rather than simply rehashing, as it  will be closed again.  IMO  the ridiculous upvote here is a protest against BSE's  system of peer regulation.    Please read the description of tags added to your question. OSM has absolutely nada to do with rigging or rigid body physics.   Thankyou.

Comment: Welcome the Blender's Stack Exchange. Please be aware that tutorial requests are off-topic on this website. The question(s) you've asked are currently very broad and would require an explanation of the entire process of rigging which exceeds the scope of what this website is for. Perhaps you can explain what particular part you're having challenges with? If it's a more specific issue we may be able to help you.